# Make two instances of d3.forceCollide() play nice together

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

I want two instances of `d3.forceCollide()`.  In one, every node is pushed away from one another to prevent overlap.  In the second, only a subset of nodes are pushed away from one another, with a much bigger radius.

To accomplish the second force, I tweak the initialize method to filter the incoming nodes, like so:

```
function selective(force,filter){
    var init = force.initialize;
    force.initialize = function(_){return init(_.filter(filter));};
    return force;
}

var dpi = 90;  // approximate pixels per inch in SVG
var size = dpi * (1/4); // quarter-inch unit size

var universally_applied = 
    d3.forceCollide()
    .radius(size)
    .strength(1);

var selectively_applied =
        selective(
            d3.forceCollide(),
            function(d){return d.id === color;}
        )
        .radius(size*5)
        .strength(1);
}
```

Now, this ALMOST works.  I created a fiddle to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/jarrowwx/0dax43ue/38/ - every colored circle is supposed to repel every other circle of the same color, from a distance.  Every other color, it just bumps into and pushes it out of the way.

If I do not change the order in which things are defined, then the selectively applied force is ONLY applied to the first color (red).  If I shuffle the `data` array before applying forces, it is difficult to define exactly what happens, but the force is applied to some circles and not most of the others, even among the same color.

Any ideas what is going on here, or how to fix it?

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. The problem is not even caused by both instances running concurrently, it also arises if you comment out the `universally_applied` force. If you additionally restrict the array of colors to only `red`, however, it [works smoothly](https://jsfiddle.net/0dax43ue/26/) as expected. It has to be a problem with the partial application of the force. I have re-checked my [answer](/a/39597440/4235784) to [*"Partial forces on nodes in D3.js"*](/q/39575319), which you adopted, but in that case it works perfectly. Still pondering...

Comment: I think there is something about shuffling the data. If I remove that step it seems to work just fine everytime I run.

Comment: @Rothrock: yes, right up until I moved red to the end of the list.

Comment: If there are 20 circles, and 5 of them are red, all the ones that are red that appear in the first 5 elements of the array get the partial force applied to them correctly.  Those that are 6 or later do not.  I think it is buried somewhere in how the force is optimized using the QuadTree.  It may have some (non-obvious) coding assumption about the nature of the input data.

Comment: I see it working with more than the first 5 reds, just tried it with 10.

Comment: I can't say exactly what is going on.  Maybe this scenario somehow triggers a bug in the QuadTree?

Comment: I've updated the original question to reflect the latest edits to the fiddle, and what I have learned so far.  I will dive in to the d3 source as I have time, but if anyone else has any ideas, they would be welcome.

Comment: @JohnArrowwood I had already written an answer which contained an analysis and an explanation, but decided not to post it because the solution did not work as I wanted. That problem might be fixable, although I am not very confident as it originates from deep within the force itself. I could scrape the pieces together and refine it a bit to have at least a partial answer, if that would be of any help. Maybe, someone comes up with a bright idea...

Comment: NEVERMIND!  I submitted a bug to d3, and they already fixed it.  The old solution will work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The D3 team decided that this behavior was a bug ([*Isolating forces to a subset of nodes? #72*](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/issues/72)), and fixed it. The fix was included in version 1.0.4 of d3-force, which is available as part of the full D3 build as of version 4.4.0.

The problem is resolved using the solution suggested by [*"Partial forces on nodes in D3.js"*](/a/39597440/4235784), and the code works as intended now.

Comment: Glad to see this resolved at last! I have added some more details to your answer, though, to make the solution easier accessible for future readers. My own answer—although it gave some hints—had its flaws and was misleading for anyone just stumbling about this. Taken into consideration that the issue is solved, I heavy-heartedly decided to delete it.

Comment: Interestingly, this happened in parallel, i.e. Mike Bostock had already started his work fixing the issue when you came up with your question.